# Groupby and then filter

Tags: python

I am trying to group by two columns of a data frame based on the condition of other.I want all the number of reviews where NYC_reviewer field is 1 and group by zipcode and year. However, I am not getting the nulls. There is one zipcode and year pair where there are no values for the given condition. I want to show this as 0.

Yelp is the data frame containing all the columns

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eiutu.png)

```
avgRatingNy = yelp[yelp['NYC_reviewer']==1]\
              .groupby(['address_zipcode', 'review_date'])['review_rating']\
              .size()
```

Comment: Did you already try to use pandas? It would be useful to insert your full code and maybe error message. Please also provide some example data.

Comment: Yes i am using data frames. Yelp is the data frame name. I am not getting any error. Just that i want to include all nulls too into the result

Comment: We need you to show the full code and also some example data, say 3-5 rows. Otherwise we can't know what *"I am not getting the nulls"* means.

Comment: Added a screenshot for the sample data

Comment: Have you tried `yelp = yelp.fillna('0')` prior to grouping?